# How to prevent changes in serialized class after serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, immutability, xmlserializer

I have this class:

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class Broker
{
    public  int Id;
    public  string Name;
    public  string Hosts;
    public  string DefaultValidatorsNameSpace;
    public  string DefaultRendererNameSpace;
    public  bool IsDefault;
    public  CrmCredentials CrmCredentials;
}
```

This class is being deserialized when the system loads, from an xml file via XmlSerializer.

I don't want to allow any programmer to change the contents of the object once it has been loaded. One way would be to make the setter private by adding `public get; private set;` to each item, but then I'll loose my serialization capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) to serialize your class, because it doesn't limit the serialization to public properties only.

Also, you don't need to specify the `[Serializable]` attribute for XML serialization.

Answer (score 0):

[YAXLib](http://yaxlib.codeplex.com) is an XML-serialization library which lets you serialize any desired fields. You don't need to expose the fields you need to serialize to public, you only need to set the option to serialize attributed fields only. This is how:

```
[YAXSerializableType(FieldsToSerialize=YAXSerializationFields.AttributedFieldsOnly)]
public sealed class Broker
{
    [YAXSerializableField]
    public  int Id { get; private set; }

    [YAXSerializableField]
    public  string Name { get; private set; }

    // or equaly give attribute to a private field
    [YAXSerializableField]
    private string _hosts;

    // and leave the property un-attributed
    public string Hosts { get { return _hosts; } }

}
```

For more information see:

http://yaxlib.codeplex.com

and

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/yaxlib.aspx